# Rails 4 and gon - not working? window.gon={};

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I am trying to use gon with rails 4 but it does not seem to be working at all.

In application.html.erb I have

```
<%= include_gon(:init => true) %>
```

I have tried with and without the init statement and have also tried placing in my controller view

In my controller I have

```
    gon.item_status = "delivered"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: item, location: item }
    end
```

In my coffee script I have

```
$ ->
  $("a[data-remote]").on "ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
    console.log(item_status)
```

In the console I see undefined and in the window source I see the following:

```
//<![CDATA[
window.gon={};
//]]>
```

So I can see that gon has loaded and is trying to get a variable, but nothing is being passed to it. Is there an issue with my controller code or is there a wider issue with rails 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access gon variables in JS using the gon object - e.g gon.item_status

For AJAX requests, you need to 'watch' the gon array with gon.watch, it doesn't update JS in the head tag with AJAX requests automatically.

See the gem homepage:

https://github.com/gazay/gon

Comment: And I can confirm gon works just fine with rails 4, I use it myself.